My CPP/CLR Form-application crashes after updating Visual Studio 2022
A couple of days ago I updated VS 2022 to its latest version 17.11.2.
This version was released just about the same time.
Now when I build and run my C++/CLR Form application I receive crashes inside ntdll.dll.
This happens in two different applications I have, which were both fully functioning up to this update.
The crash is before any of my code is running.
My breakpoint on first line of main is never reached.
The crash is during CLR application startup:
ntdll.dll!00007fffd90af6e0()    Unknown
KernelBase.dll!00007fffd6a351bb()   Unknown
ucrtbased.dll!00007fff0f6b24d7()    Unknown
ucrtbased.dll!00007fff0f6b2f1e()    Unknown
MyApp.exe!_onexit(int(*)() function=0x00007ff6ea6d0f20) Line 267    C++
MyApp.exe!atexit(void(*)() function=0x00007ff6ea6d0f20) Line 275    C++
MyApp.exe!std::`dynamic atexit destructor for '_Fac_tidy_reg''() Line 64    C++
[Managed to Native Transition]  
MyApp.exe!_initterm(void (__cdecl*)()* pfbegin=0x00000052842fdc40, void (__cdecl*)()* pfend=0x00000052842fdc48) Line 126    C++
MyApp.exe!<CrtImplementationDetails>::LanguageSupport::InitializeNative() Line 359  C++
MyApp.exe!<CrtImplementationDetails>::LanguageSupport::_Initialize() Line 598   C++
MyApp.exe!<CrtImplementationDetails>::LanguageSupport::Initialize() Line 805    C++
MyApp.exe!.cctor() Line 857 C++
[Native to Managed Transition]  
[Managed to Native Transition]  
[Native to Managed Transition]  
mscoreei.dll!00007fffbb50d6ea() Unknown
mscoree.dll!00007fffbc7aac42()  Unknown
kernel32.dll!00007fffd7ee7374() Unknown
ntdll.dll!00007fffd909cc91()    Unknown

If anyone know how to work-around this please let me know.
Also - if there a way to roll-back to a specific previous release please let me know.
Meanwhile beware of this specific version...

Have you made any changes in the code between it seemingly working, and it no longer working? Have you tried to debug the program (catch the crash in your debugger)? When in your code does the crash happen? What are the values of all involved variables at the time of the crash? And can you please try to create a proper [mre] to show us?

As for how the crash suddenly appeared after just doing an update, it's very likely that there's some undefined behavior in your code that seemed to work before, but now no longer do that. Do you use uninitialized variables? Invalid or null pointers?

@Someprogrammerdude - no changes at all. Just rebuild after update. I wrote where the crash happens and supplied stack, thus also debugged, but no valuable information as these are system modules

You need to not only catch the crash in the debugger, but also walk up the call stack until you get to your code. The problem is more likely somewhere in your code, than in the Windows code. And if it crashes immediately before the main function is even called, then the problem is either in a static/global object initialization or a stack overflow. But still in your code.

@Someprogrammerdude there are no global variables in CLR. I know to debug and all info is already in the question. Please allow to others to response. Thanks.

Example

Apparently this is a regression that came with one of the last Visual Studio 2022 Community updates. I am not sure exactly with which one, as I did not update my VS for a while, but I noticed it after updating to 17.11.2.
Context
Until now, in a C++/CLI application, you could select a different clr runtime support per each C++ file. Typically you would select No CLR support for C++ files containing pure native code, and /clr for files, which need to utilize .NET libraries.
These settings are done using the Common Language Runtime Support option, found under Project Settings | C/C++ | General. 
This setting can be done per C++ file:

The Bug
As from this regression, if you select No Common Language Runtime Support for some of your C++ files, you could receive the runtime crash reported above.
Workaround
Set all your files to /clr.
This may issue the following warning for some of your functions, but apart from this all will work:
warning C4793: 'foo': function compiled as native


We were plagued with the same issue and removing the /NOENTRY flag from the CLI project settings worked for us. We don't have an entry point and skipping this flag doesn't seem to give any issues for us.
This crash doesn't happen when using build tools v143 (v14.36). Anything later than that crashes the app with "dynamic atexit destructor for" error.
If anyone can elaborate why this is happening, it would be extremely helpful!

You can roll back Visual Studio version using Visual Studio Installer.
More -> Rollback to previous version


You can download the old version use cmd
1.
Download VisualStudioSetup.exe
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes-v17.10
2.
This step requires uninstalling Visual Studio first. Use CMD
visualstudiosetup.exe --channelUri https://aka.ms/vs/17/release.LTSC.17.10/channel



Thank you for this answer. For some reason I do not have the 'Rollback' option in my 'More' options

@PazO I updated my answer. You can use LTSC version.
